# Evaluation of $x$ in $\log_{\frac{3}{4}}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = -2$

Tags: logarithms

> Evaluation of $x$ in $$\log_{\frac{3}{4}}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = -2$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Here $x>0\;,$ Now Using Properties of $\log\;,$ We get $$\log_{\frac{3}{4}}(x)-\log_{\frac{3}{4}}\left(3\right)+\log_{\frac{1}{2}}(x)+1=-2$$

So $$\log_{\frac{3}{4}}(x)+\log_{\frac{1}{2}}(x)=-3+\log_{\frac{3}{4}}\left(3\right)$$

Now How can I solve after that , Help Required, Thanks

Comment: Make them a common base, use $\log_a(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(a)}$, after that exponentiate the whole equation by $e$.

Comment: $x=4$ clearly satisfies this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\log_2(x)-\log_2(3)}{\log_2(3)-\log_2(4)}+\frac{\log_2(x)-\log_2(2)}{\log_2(1)-\log_2(2)}=-2$$

$$\frac{\log_2(x)-\log_2(3)}{\log_2(3)-2}+\frac{\log_2(x)-1}{0-1}=-2$$

$$\frac{\log_2(x)-\log_2(3)}{\log_2(3)-2}+1-\log_2(x)=-2$$

$$\frac{\log_2(x)-\log_2(3)}{\log_2(3)-2}=-3+\log_2(x)$$

$$\log_2(x)(\frac1{\log_2(3)-2}-1)=-3+\frac{\log_2(3)}{\log_2(3)-2}$$
$$\log_2(x)\frac{3-\log_2(3)}{\log_2(3)-2}=\frac{6-2\log_2(3)}{\log_2(3)-2}$$

$$\log_2(x)=2$$

$$x=4$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Using [Laws of Logarithms](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laws_of_Logarithms),

$$\log_{\frac34}\dfrac x3=\dfrac{\log_2(x/3)}{\log_2(3/4)}=\dfrac{\log_2x-\log_23}{\log_23-2}$$

and $$\log_{\frac12}\dfrac x2=\dfrac{\log_2(x/2)}{\log_2(2^{-1})}=1-\log_2x$$